# How can I find out the dates when Magento releases new versions?

Tags: upgrade

I've been looking at the main Magento DevDocs site here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.4CE.html

But I can't find the dates when each of the point releases came out.
Is there somewhere else I need to look to find out this information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , its documentation related question , not related to coding

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Release Archive tab on the Magento website's [download page](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download).

Another option is to check the dates of when each tag was released on the [Magento GitHub repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tags).